# How to disable F7 F8 F9 function for Quick Time Player

Tags: macos, quicktime

I have OS X 10.11, Quick Time Player 10.4.

My question is simple, how do you disable <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> function keys in QT Player?

I want to use these keys for iTunes, but I really need to keep some of the movies open. But whenever I press <kbd>F8</kbd>, it will activate iTunes and QuickTime Player at the same time. Then I have to dig into QT Player and stop it.

Is there a way to disable the <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> functions for QT?